# System.InvalidOperationException when trying to mock a dependency and register with an IoC container

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, testing, moq, castle-windsor

We have an interface...

```
public interface IService<T> where T : class
{
}
```

...which I need to mock as part of a component test project and register with a Castle Windsor container.

All I care about is that this interface has an implementation registered with the container to satisfy dependencies in the project.

I've found there's no way to generically mock such an interface (`Mock<IService<>>`? `Mock<T, IService<T>>`?) so I created a dummy class...

```
public class FakeT
{
}
```

...and registered the servcie like this...

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IService<>), typeof(Mock<IService<FakeT>>)).LifestyleTransient());
```

...which at least compiles, but when I run a test, at the point Castle Windsor tries to resolve this dependency it throws the following exception:

> [My.Namespace.IService`1[My.Tests.FakeT]] is not a
>   GenericTypeDefinition. MakeGenericType may only be called on a type
>   for which Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition is true.'

I'm obviously getting this totally wrong, so hopefully you can help :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that implements your interface:

```
public class SomeClass : IService<FakeT>
{
}
```

Then register that class and interface:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IService<FakeT>>().
.ImplementedBy<SomeClass>()
.LifestyleTransient());
```

Comment: Thank you, but this way I can't benefit from mocking the behaviour of `SomeClass` using my chosen mock framework. Is this just not possible in my scenario?

Comment: @getsetcode Really though, `SomeClass` would be an instance of type `IService<FakeT>` so it isn't that you'd be mocking `SomeClass`, you're going to be mocking an implementation of `IService<FakeT>`. To make it more generic you could have it implement `IService<Object>`.